# How can I automatically log users session out without clicking first

Tags: javascript, php, timeout

I made a site that is user-based and so far I've been able to easily handle the sessions up to this point. I'm not a noob when it comes to php, but I don't have a good working knowledge of javascript. I have set a timeout for my users so that they are automatically timed out after 20 minutes of *inactivity*. It works great, other than they need to click a link or refresh in order for the session to actually be timed out. This is my current php timeout.

```
<?php

//TIMEOUT AFTER 20 MINUTES
if(isset($_SESSION['signed_in'])) {

$inactive = 1200;

if(isset($_SESSION['timeout']) ) {
$session_life = time() - $_SESSION['timeout'];
if($session_life > $inactive) { 
    $id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

    //this db row is solely to display # of users logged in
    mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE users SET user_signedin='0' WHERE user_id = '$id'");
    session_destroy();
    $_SESSION = array();
    header("Location: timedout.php"); 
}
}
$_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
}
?>
```

But I've also tried javascript (setting the timer to 5 minutes) like so:

```
<script>
var wintimeout;

function SetWinTimeout() {
wintimeout = window.setTimeout("window.location.href='timedout.php';",300000);
 }
 $('body').click(function() {

window.clearTimeout(wintimeout); //when user clicks remove timeout and reset it

SetWinTimeout();

});
 SetWinTimeout();
 </script>
```

I've searched a number of different places to find out how to implement an automatic redirect without having to click or refresh, but so far no luck. How do people redirect automatically (without clicking or refreshing) upon timeout?

**EDIT:** For people who are looking for the same answer: Ok, I was able to get the desired effect by adding this to my page header

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['signed_in'])) { ?>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1800;url=internal.php" />
?>
```

"internal.php" is very similar to the first piece of code I pasted above, though I've taken out the piece where it checks for timeout. However, now I'm having problems with people exiting the tab and not getting signed out, but that's a whole other issue.

Comment: All I can say is that although your client-side code will work, you should not pass a string to `setTimeout()` as it is handled as an `eval()` operation. Instead, you should pass a function: `setTimeout(function(){ location.href = "timedout.php"; }, 300000);`. That should redirect you to the .php file, which should then do it's thing.

Comment: So I changed the code to match your comment... but it still isn't automatically logging the user out. I'm looking to have the page automatically redirect the user to "timedout.php" saying that they have been signed out due to inactivity. So far I can log them out, but not until they click a link or refresh the page. The code isn't auto-redirecting them...